# What does a MANOVA tell me about my data?

Tags: r, manova

I have a dependent variable which is measured in two different areas (DV1,DV2).  I want to see if the relationship my independent variable (IV) has with each DV is transferable to the other DV i.e. if we know the relationship between DV1 and IV, can this be used to successfully predict DV2, and vice versa.

People have advised me to carry out a MANOVA in order to do this, with Y containing DV1 and DV2 and x containing IV.  I am a little confused with MANOVA however, as I am not sure if it is telling me what I want to know.  Can someone please explain exactly what a MANOVA analysis can tell me about my data?  I have posted my two outputs below.

Some code I have used:

```
Y <- cbind(DV1,DV2)
fit <- manova(Y ~ E)

summary(fit)
```

gives me the output:

```
                   Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
E                  1 0.40252    13.81      2     41 2.598e-05 ***
Residuals          42                                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

`summary.aov(fit)` gives me:

```
Response 1 :
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
E                  1  1.123 1.12299  27.826 4.341e-06 ***
Residuals          42  1.695 0.04036                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Response 2 :
                   Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
E                  1 0.41248 0.41248  7.5361 0.008862 **
Residuals          42 2.29884 0.05473                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

For reference, I am actually using a pgls based MANOVA using code from "Outomuro, D., D.C. Adams, and F. Johansson. 2013. Evolution of wing shape in ornamented-winged damselflies. Evolutionary Biology."  But I thought for illustratve purposes it would be easier to stick to the normal non-phylogenetic MANOVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MANOVA tries to find a linear combination of the dependent variables that is well explained by the independent variables. It seems to have done this for your data. I don't think that's the question you posed.

To answer the question you posed, you could do 2 multiple regressions: DV1 against IV and DV2. Then DV2 against IV and DV1.

Comment: Hi Placidia - thanks for your answer.  Could you please explain the reasoning behind your suggested solution?  Many thanks.

Comment: Sure. That's what regression does. you are saying that dv1=a*dv2+b*iv+ error and dv2=c*dv1+b*iv. So fit the regressions and see if the coefficients for iv are similar. To do this "right" you probably need a simple structural equation model.